# To prove the given statement

Tags: group-theory

If G is a finite group, show that there is a positive integer N such that a^N = e for all a in G.
I am not getting any hint, as I am always afraid from things that are obvious . I am sure this proof is in few steps but I am not getting how to start.

Comment: Maybe start by proving that for every $a$ there is an $N_a$ such that $a^{N_a}=e$.  But one can with some machinery prove a much stronger result.

Comment: Sorry, I dont think it works for me, still waiting for hint

Comment: OK, in a while I can write an answer.

Comment: If the elements are $\{a_0, \dots, a_n\}$, each has an order $m_i$, where $a_i^{m_i} = e$. So $n = \mathsf{lcm}(m_0, \dots, m_n)$ does the trick.

Comment: Before thinking off what all elements do, think of what one element does.  Take a in G, an ordinary element.  Consider a, a^2, a^3, a^4 etc.  will this ever equal e?  If so when?

Comment: @fleablood & OP — (...If so when?) and then, How often, subsequently? i.e. do these recurring equalities to $e$ ever sync up?

Comment: This could use a descriptive title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a \in G$ , where $G$ is a finite group.

Now by the closure property, that is if $a,b \in G \Rightarrow a*b \in G$

So we have that $a*a = a^2 \in G$

Similarly $a^2*a = a^3\in G$

Proceeding in this manner we have that $a*a*a*....*a=a^m \in G$ for some $m \in\mathbb Z^+$

But $G$ is finite . So there exists $n \in \mathbb Z $ such that $a^m=a^n$.

So we have that  $ a^{m-n} =e $ . Clearly $m-n \in \mathbb Z^+  $

So there is $M=m-n \in \mathbb Z^+$ such that $a^M=e$.

So the order of $a$ is $M$ .

Thus by lagrange's theorem $ O(a) | O(G)$ that is $M$ divides $O(G)$

So for any $a \in G$ , there exists $M_a$ such that $a^{M_a}=e$

if $O(G)=N $ then we can find an integer $k$ such that $O(G)=N=k \cdot M_a$.

So for any $a \in G$ , $({a^{M_a}})^k=a^{O(G)}=a^N=e$.

Comment: But that only shows there is an N for a, if you do that for b you will get an M which may not equal N.  The question asked to find a single N that works for all all elements.  Not just one.

Comment: Yours was easy to understand, thank you.

Comment: The element a is taken arbitrary,  so works for all a.

Comment: No.  The number N was determined by a.  So it may not work for another element b.

Comment: All elements have *a* number that works for *that* single element.  You need to find a universal number that works for *all* elements.

Comment: @Angelo Mark. It would be all perfect of you take n ,m in set of positive integers, you can edit it.

Answer (score 5):

Let $a\in G$. Consider the elements $a$, $a^2$, $a^3$, $a^4$, and so on forever. The group is finite, so these elements cannot be all distinct. It follows that there exist exponents $i$ and $j$, with $i\lt j$, such that $a^i=a^j$. But then $a^{j-i}=e$.

We have shown that for any $a$, there exists a positive integer $N_a$ such that $a^{N_a}=e$.

Now let $N$ be the product of the $N_a$, or their least common multiple. Then for any $a$ we have $N=q_aN_a$ for some integer $q_a$. Then
$$a^N=(a^{N_a})^{q_a}=e^{q_a}=e.$$

**Remark:** Consider the subgroup $G_a$ generated by $a$. It is not difficult to show that $a^{|G_a|}=e$, where $|G_a|$ denotes the number  of elements of $G_a$.

Maybe you have already seen a theorem to the effect that the order of any subgroup divides the order of the group. If you haven't, you soon will.  From that it follows that $a^{|G|}=e$ for all $a$.

Answer (score 2):

Given G is a finite group, then there cannot be infinitely many different elements in G.

Take any $a \in G$. If a^n is different for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then it contradicts $G$ being finite. So let say for some $0\leq i< j$, we have $a^i = a^j$.

Now multiply by $a^{-i}$ on both side. We get $e=a^{j-i}$.

If you take the LCD of all these $j-i$ for all $a$ in $G$, that would be the $N$ we are asked to find

Proof complete.

Comment: The only shows that each element has a number that works for it.  We were supposed to find a single number that works for *all* elements.

Comment: that's right. I modified my answer